# Spring Boot Mapear Arquivos Estáticos (React)

Tags: node.js, react, spring, spring-boot, router

Minha dúvida é, como faço para mapear arquivos estáticos, por exemplo no NodeJS usando Express, eu posso:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Assim todas requisições eu envio para o index.html, tem algo equivalente no Spring Boot?
O motivo de eu querer isto é para rodar o React no ambiente de produção dentro do servidor web do spring, se isto que estou pensando em fazer é errado/gambiarra tem outra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom Dia,

Beleza?

Cara, tem como sim mas eu achei meio estranho como você quer utilizar isso ai.

De qualquer forma, no site deles mesmo (Spring) tem um tutorial basicão pra fazer isso que você quer, acho que pode te ajudar.

Segue o link:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Abraço.